# Changing the homepage

Tags: homepage

Is it possible to change the Home page so it's not a blog, but a page? And also is it possible to change the name of the homepage?

If yes, how is this done?

Thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the **site Front Page** to be a *static Page*:

- Go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading`
- Change **Front page displays** from *Your latest posts* to *A static page*
- In the dropdown beneath this option, select the static Page to use as your Front Page.
- If you want to display your blog Posts somewhere, select a static Page to use to display them.

To change the **title** of your Front Page:

- The Front Page will assume the *Page Title* of whatever static Page you selected above.