# How do I change theme demo

Tags: themes, add-theme-support

I have purchased a theme from envato and the theme came with a bunch of different demos. I am trying to use the "app landing" demo. It has already been installed but I am not able to make it my main page. Can someone help?

Thank you!
Kelvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the homepage through the settings. [As stated in this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/25212/98212):

- Go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading`
- Change **Front page displays** from *Your latest posts* to *A static page*
- In the dropdown beneath this option, select the static Page to use as your Front Page.
- If you want to display your blog Posts somewhere, select a static Page to use to display them.

To change the **title** of your Front Page:

- The Front Page will assume the *Page Title* of whatever static Page you selected above.

Comment: @kelvin Glad that worked for you. Please click the checkmark next to my answer to indicate that this question has been solved.